# Spring Boot metrics http.client.requests do not work for WebClient reactive applications

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, reactive

I have a spring boot 2.2.2 microservices, which integrations with other services using WebClient (rective). According to Spring documentation, the actuator should return "http.client.requests" metrics by default as Timer is enabled by default. But it does not work for me. I am able to get http.server.requests" metrics.

My WebClient is a bean configured and build with WebClient.builder(), as documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-http-clients

Answer (score 6):

Use Spring Boot's preconfigured `WebClient.Builder` instead of `WebClient.builder()` to have an instance of `WebClient`.

You can find more detail [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webclient).

As in the following you can have a bean of `WebClient`.

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        return webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl("https://example.org")
                .build();
    }
}
```

`WebClient.Builder` is an Auto-configuration, means the injected point above will receive a newly cloned instance of the builder.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientAutoConfiguration.java#L50) is the source for `WebClientAutoConfiguration`

Comment: When I startup the application, my `ClientConfiguration` always init before `WebClientAutoConfiguration`, that causes Metric Config not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed my application has to make a WebClient call before the `metrics/http.client.requests` endpoint exists. Prior to my application making a WebClient call that endpoint isn't discoverable and returns NOT FOUND.

Hope that helps others in a similar situation!